# consolidated testresults for multiple testsuites using testng listeners

Tags: java, testng, listener, suite

I have Sanity testsuite testng xml which contains multiple testsuites and I want to get results of Sanity testsuite and display on console.

I tried using IsuiteListener and I am getting results of individual test suites.

Can someone help me in getting consolidated results for all the testsuites running under sanity testsuite?

```
package utilities;

import java.util.Map;

import org.testng.ISuite;
import org.testng.ISuiteListener;
import org.testng.ISuiteResult;
import org.testng.Reporter;

public class Listener implements ISuiteListener 
{

    @Override
    public void onStart(ISuite arg0) {
        Reporter.log("About to begin executing Suite " + arg0.getName(), true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish(ISuite suite) 
    {
        Map<String,ISuiteResult> results=suite.getResults();
        for(String key: results.keySet())
        {
             ISuiteResult con = results.get(key);

            int totaltestcases=con.getTestContext().getAllTestMethods().length;

        int passtestcases= con.getTestContext().getPassedTests().size();
        int failedtestcases=con.getTestContext().getFailedTests().size();
        int skippedtestcases=con.getTestContext().getSkippedTests().size();
        int percentage=(passtestcases*100)/totaltestcases;
        System.out.println("PASS PERCENTAGE : "+percentage+"%");

        }
    }



}
```

**Below is the Sanity Test Suite xml**

```
<suite name="Sanity Test Suite">
<listeners>

 <listener class-name="utilities.Listener"></listener>

 </listeners>
   <suite-files>
    <suite-file path="TestSuit_01.xml"/>
    <suite-file path="TestSuit_02.xml"/>

</suite-files>
</suite>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should build an implementation of the TestNG listener `org.testng.IReporter` which gets executed after all the suites have run to completion and then refer to this listener in your suite xml file via the `<listeners>` tag.

Comment: Hi @Krishnan, I tried with IReporter but now suite.getresults is not returning anything.ISuite suite = suites.get(0);
     Map<String,ISuiteResult> results=suite.getResults();
     for ( ISuiteResult sr : results.values() ) {
            ITestContext tc = sr.getTestContext();
            System.out.println("Passed tests for suite '" + suite.getName() + "' is:" +
                 tc.getPassedTests().getAllResults().size());
          } code is not going into loop

Comment: @Yashica - That is a basic use case for `IReporter`. So I would be surprised to hear that it doesnt work. Can you please post your complete code on perhaps github and share the link so that I can take a look at it to see what is going wrong ?

Comment: Since i am using suite.get(0) which is my sanity suite here and it doesnot have any testresults thats why results.value() was coming as null. i resolved by summation of every other testcase result and then displaying the consolidated report. thank you so much for your help !!